# Why does the following relationship hold?

Tags: particle-physics

My problem is the following:

[image]

During the solution the following relationship is found to be true (last two lines):

[image]

Namely, $E_{e}=|\overrightarrow{p_{e}}| \cdot \beta_{e} $, where $\beta_{e}$ is the velocity of the incoming electron.

Why is this the case?

Thanks,

T.D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have if $c=1$:

$$E = m\gamma$$

$$\mathbf{p} = m\gamma\boldsymbol{\beta}$$

Taking the norm of the second one and dividing the first one by the second one you get:

$$\frac{E}{p} = \beta$$

This is the relation that is used in the exercise.